# Exited (14) Persistencia de mongodb en un contenedor

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Cordial saludo amigos

En el proceso de seguir ese caso [Caso similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50930008/docker-mongodb-data-not-persistent?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Al momento de correr el contenedor la maquina no corre correctamente debido a que internamente en el contenedor el servicio de mongodb tiene ocupados los archivos en la ruta /data/db. Dentro de la carpeta de persistencia no hay archivos
¿Que puedo hacer colegas?

Este es mi docker-compose

```
          services:
        mongodb:
          build: ./Mongo
          ports:
            - "${PUERTO_MONGODB}:27017"
          container_name: ${NAME_MONGODB}
          volumes:
            - ./mongo/persistencia:/data/db
          networks:
             FortNet:
                ipv4_address: ${IP_MONGODB}
```

Este es mi dockerfile

```
FROM mongo
EXPOSE 27017
```

Comment: la configuracion del volumen lo debe tener el docker o , en este caso lo tiene el docker.-compose,pero como estas haciendo un docker toda la configuracion debe estar alli, te propongo cambiar la linea del `build: ./Mongo`: y por `image: mongo`  asi toda la configuracion la tiene el docker-compose

Comment: Si lo hice asi como dices pero sucedio lo mismo, exactamente el mismo error

Comment: cual es el error? debes verificar si tu configuracion de docker tienes habilitado el compartir archivos

Comment: Cuando se ejecuta el comando **doker-compose up -d** y posteriormente se hace el comando **docker ps -a** sale el siguiente error con el contenedor **mongo                                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Exited (14) 4 seconds ago                                                                         MongoS** @JackNavaRow

Comment: y para modo pruebas, te recomiento quitar el -d, la consola te puede dar mas detalle del error, puede ser incluso que no tiene permisos en la carpeta donde tiene que escribir

Comment: ejecute tu docker-compose y no tuve problemas, verifica los permisos de escritura, si usas windows probablemente [te haga falta esta configuracion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55764194/5695795)